# Python: Get first element of list potentially containing sublists

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for the first element of a Python list potentially containing either numbers (integer or float), or many levels of nested sublists containing the same.  In these examples, let's suppose I am always looking for the number '1'.  If the list contains no sublists, we have:

```
>>> foo = [1,2,3]
>>> foo[0]
1
```

If the list contains one sublist, and I know this information, I can again obtain 1 with

```
>>> foo = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> foo[0][0]
1
```

Similarly if the first element of my list is a list containing a list:

```
>>> foo = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
>>> foo[0][0][0]
1
```

Is there a general way to get the first integer or float in `foo`, without resorting to calling a function recursively until drilling down to a value of `foo[0]` that is no longer a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need for recursion. Assuming that you are always working with `list`s and `int`s, this should work perfectly well for you.

```
foo = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]

result = None
while True:
    try:
        result = foo[0]
    except TypeError:
        break
```

Unlike the other answers, this asks for forgiveness rather than for permission, which is a bit more Pythonic.

If you *really* want to be Pythonic, you could define a function like as follows. However, this would admittedly be overkill given your specification.

```
def first_scalar(foo):
    result = None
    while True:
        try:
            result = next(iter(foo))
        except TypeError:
            return result
```

*Note that it returns `None` if the argument is not an `iterable`.* The same applies for the first segment of code.

*Note that this doesn't work if the if the deepest "left-most" child list is empty.* To account for this, you'll need to totally flatten the list.

```
def _flatten(foo):
    try:
        for item in foo:
            yield from flatten(foo)
    except TypeError:
        yield foo

def flatten(foo):
    for item in foo:
        yield from _flatten(foo)

def first_scalar(foo):
    return next(flatten(foo))
```

*Note that the above must be written in at least Python 3.3.*

The following code is for earlier versions of Python.

```
def _flatten(foo):
    try:
        for item in foo:
            for subitem in _flatten(foo):
                yield subitem
    except TypeError:
        yield foo

def flatten(foo):
    for item in foo:
        for subitem in _flatten(foo):
            yield subitem
```

Comment: Eww now you're building a bunch of iterators just to throw them away. The actual best way to do this is referenced in my answer: fix your data type. Anything else is a hack by definition. Stop trying to finesse the hack -- just document it.

Comment: I don't know what OP is trying to do. Given the question, the best that one can do is to answer the question instead of hinting at the XY Problem without any helpful information on how to do X instead of Y or any inquires to try determine what X would be.

Comment: YMMV, but when someone asks me how to drive in a nail with a screwdriver, I advise them to use a screw instead, rather than telling them to try hitting it with the handle.

Comment: With your analogy, what I'm saying is that we don't know if OP is using a nail, screw, bolt, or whatever else.

Comment: I thank you for the Pythonic answer, Tyler - this is what I was getting as (I did specifically ask for a way to do this without a recursion function call, after all). I am newish to Python, @Adam Smith, so forgive me if this is a stupid question - but is it not valid to have a list containing multiple data types?

Comment: @JCOidl, it is perfectly valid, but it's just generally frowned upon.

Comment: @JCOidl it's a bit like being drunk underage in the U.S.. It's not illegal, it's just generally a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2):

The general-case answer for this is "Fix your data structure." Lists are supposed to be homogeneous, e.g. every element of the list should have the same type (be that `int` or `list of ints` or `list of lists of ints` or etc).

The special case here would be to recurse until you find a number and return it.

```
def foo(lst):
    first_el = lst[0]
    if isinstance(first_el, (float, int)):
        return first_el
    else:
        return foo(first_el)
```

Comment: @TylerCrompton so would `["gotcha!", ...]` but I'm not going to imagine edge cases that aren't presented. That would make this literally impossible (what if the 3-deep first element is a class inheriting list that is sliceable but doesn't implement `__iter__` and contains an object inheriting str and int that behaves like an `int` if it can, else behaves like a `str`?)

Comment: @TylerCrompton it's assumed that the lists won't be empty in the same breath that it's assumed to be passed a list.

Comment: The edge case that you mentioned does not make sense, and we have no reason to believe that it would be prominent. A sliceable object that is not iterable and is also a subclass of `int` and `str`? That is just so unrealistic that it's not worth mentioning. It's not stated that the cardinality of the sub-lists will always be the same. Despite the sample inputs implying otherwise, I think it's reasonable to assume that it's a possibility without further information. Besides, it should be obvious that the sample inputs are simplified examples.

Answer (score 1):

create a simple, recursive function:

```
>>> def getFirst(l):
    return l[0] if not isinstance(l[0],list) else getFirst(l[0])

>>> getFirst([1,2,3,4])
1
>>> getFirst([[1,2,3],[4,5]])
1
>>> getFirst([[[4,2],12,[1,3]],1])
4
```

this will return `l[0]` if `l[0]` is anything but a list. else, it will return the first item of `l[0]` recursively

Comment: The conditional statement is a bit wordy, but otherwise exactly what I'd do (and what I did in my answer! :P)

Comment: yeah I figured this might be a little more verbose than `if isinstance(l[0], (int,float,..)` since it can accept a list of any object type. i originally had what you had but decided against it :P

Comment: The general solution is to do `hasattr(el, "__iter__")` or `isinstance(el, collections.abc.Iterable)`, but that includes strings which is usually not intended!

Comment: That's a good answer and it should work but OP specifically asks for a non-recursive way to do this.

Comment: Oh, huh, I didn't either.

Comment: Not a problem @rnar.  I've learned a lot from these answers regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can just "dive in", without any recursion:

```
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
first = lst
while isinstance(first, list):
    first = first[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to avoid any loops or recursion, there is an **ugly** workaround. Transform the list to a string and then remove the list-specific chars:

```
','.join(map(str,foo)).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(' ','').split(',')
```

Of course it only works if the list is composed by strings or integers. If the objects in the list are custom, you would have to transform them to string. But, since there is an unknown number of sublists, you would have to use recursion, so using this workaround wouldn't make sense.

Another thing, maybe the elements of the list and sublists have the same chars as the list-specific ones, such as '[' or ',', so that would also be a problem.

In short, this is a **bad** workaround that only works for sure if the list and sublists are composed of numbers. Otherwise, using some kind of recursion is most probably necessary.

Comment: Every one of those functions and methods are implemented recursively, so it doesn't avoid recursion. Admittedly, it's impossible to avoid loops to answer this question though.

Comment: @TylerCrompton ah, okay. Then this answer is even worse than I initially thought. Thanks.